# Angular 4 with Docker and Nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have an Angular project developed without Docker and I'm trying to migrate it to Docker. I have created the project with Angular CLI and all CLI commands works fine.

I have used the `ng build` to create the final production build. The command worked fine and I have a `/dist` folder with the bundled application.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

I build the project with `docker build -t nikhilbaby/testing12 .` and ran the project with `docker run -p 80:80 -it nikhilbaby/testing12`. I get the following error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint priceless_bassi (94fb94bb6ba5f722eab0701e0f3e805f50ee53cc522aa65f7ffe4fc103a47a76): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
```

I'm new to docker and please forgive me if this is a silly mistake from my part.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. The port 80 was used by some other process. I have changed

```
docker run -p 80:80 -it nikhilbaby/testing12
```

to

```
docker run --name angular-app -p 8080:80 -d  nikhilbaby/testing12
```

I can access the site in `http://localhost:8080/`